# SonarQube analysis fails on ES2015 syntax - but it's apparently supported?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, ecmascript-6

It says here (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Plugin) that the SonarQube JS plugin has supported ES6 (which I believe is also know as ES2015) since version 2.0.

I have version 2.8 installed in SonarQube 4.5.6, but I see errors like this in my analysis log -

```
17:54:58.185 ERROR - Parse error at line 21 column 17:

     'individualIndex': -1,
     'individualName': {},
     'individualSearchResults': [],
     'individualEmail': '',
     'individualMobile': '',
     'dunsNumberRequired': false,
     'allDone': false
    });
  }

  static actions = {
                 ^
```

...and that looks to me like SonarRunner is tripping on the `static` keyword.

So - does SonarQube *really* support ES2015? Or do I need to configure it differently, perhaps? My config is as follows -

```
sonar.projectKey=my-project
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=$BUILD_NUMBER
sonar.exclusions=node_modules/**,tests/**,bin/**,config/**,docs/
sonar.sources=.
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=coverage/lcov.info
```

Thanks.

Comment: That code is not ES2015. ES2015 does not support (static) class properties.

Comment: @zeroflagL Ah, that might well be why I'm confused, thanks. Would that code be ES2016, then?

Comment: No. ES2016 will be a minor update. Class properties are still a proposal and it can take a while to get into the standard. If it ever gets there.

Comment: Got it, thanks. If you want to post an answer telling me the code I'm scanning sin't ES2015 I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static actions = {
```

This is a static class property and those are not part of the ES 2015 spec. So the SonarQube JS plugin is right to complain about it. Class properties are currently at a proposal stage, so it's unclear when (or if) they will make it into the language.

The status and development of the ECMAScript language can be confusing at times. The fact that transpilers support most proposals (i.e. features that are not part of any specification yet) makes the situation even worse.

If you want to target a specific version of ECMAScript, but are unsure about the supported features, then you can, of course, consult the [language sepecification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html). I can also recommend [this compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).